# Dricore Subfloor membrane panel 23.25 inch x 23.25 inch

Tags: vinyl-flooring

I am laying sheet vinyl on a Dricore Subfloor membrane panel 23.25 inch x 23.25 inch sub floor do I need to do anything more before I lay the vinyl

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Please take our [tour](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: Is it full glue down, loose lay or edge glued?